# UIImageView returns nil in customView

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I have created a customView and inside the customView, there is an imageView. When i pass the control to customView and print out my imageView, it returns null. Not sure why.

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface GalleryImage : UIView
{
    IBOutlet UIImageView *galleryImageView;
}
- (id)initWithImage:(UIImage*) image;
@property(strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImage *galleryImage;
@end
```

.m

```
#import "GalleryImage.h"

@implementation GalleryImage

@synthesize galleryImage;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}
- (id)initWithImage:(UIImage*) image
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        galleryImage = image;
        [galleryImageView setImage:galleryImage];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Pass the control this way:

```
UIImage *infoImage = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];

GalleryImage *galleryItem = [[GalleryImage alloc] initWithImage:infoImage];
```

But my galleryImageView returns null. Any idea why?

Comment: Was the view created in IB or in code? If created in code, did you add it to the view? Did you hook up the outlet?

Comment: Does the `galleryImageView` itself return null or is its image null?

Comment: I created a view in IB and made the custom class = GalleryImage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`galleryImageView` is an IBOutlet and it gets a memory only after it is loaded from the nib .The init method is executed before it .Hence imageview does not have valid memory and it returns null

Do it in

```
awakeFromNib
Prepares the receiver for service after it has been loaded from an Interface Builder archive, or nib file.
```

So use this

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
        [galleryImageView setImage:galleryImage];
}
```

Comment: thanks.. get the point.. meaning to say that init method is called before the nib file is initialised...